# Bound and parity integer-partition into fixed number of parts

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $E(n,k)$ denote how many set of $k$ distinct non-negative integer are there such that their sum is an even number $\leq n$.

Let $O(n,k)$ denote how many set of $k$ distinct non-negative integer are there such that their sum is an odd number $\leq n$.

Find all values of $n,k$ such that $E(n,k)=O(n,k)$.

My attempts so far: for $k=1$ only when $n$ is even. For $k=2$ it never works.

Conjecture: $k=1,n$ even are the only possibility.

Thank you for your help.